# How to simplify this expression？

Tags: expression, simplification

F(A,B,C)=ABC+A'BC+A'BC'+AB'C+AC'
how to simplify this expression?
Need help...
Thanks.
How would you simplify this boolean expression? I don't know how to apply the boolean laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABC+A'B(C+C')+AB'C+AC' ==
ABC+A'B+ABC+AC'==
AC(B+B')+A'B+AC'==
AC+A'B+AC'==
A+A'B==
A+B
```

Comment: that is one of the rules.. you can prove it as tautology by giving values to a and b

Answer (score -1):

I haven't don't this in a long time. :(

```
F(A,B,C)=ABC+A'BC+A'BC'+AB'C+AC'
(A + A')BC+A'BC'+AB'C+AC'
BC+A'BC'+AB'C+AC'
B(C+A'C')+A(B'C+C')
```